# How can I store the user details (ip, name, duration) after login using php ?

Tags: php, authentication, ip

In my application, I want to store the user details (ip, name, duration) after login. Duration means **How long the user stay as login in my application ?** using php.
I found IP Address using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`
And time using `time()`
And how to find the duration ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your logout page should contain a query where you will make note of the time, then calculate the difference from there (substraction), then make that change in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `$_SESSION` Variable:

```
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

Duration can be calculated with a simple mathematical operation. Your code (might) look like this:

```
$_SESSION['initial_timestamp'] = time();
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
$_SESSION['duration'] = $_SESSION['timestamp'] - $_SESSION['initial_timestamp'] ;
```

This (should) calculate the time of the logged in user since his first log in

Comment: but i need time in hours:minutes:seconds method

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

- You should make time entry at **log on** time
- You should make time entry at **log out** time
- Then **calculate difference** of both time.

Comment: [`Which is exactly what I said`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754211/how-can-i-store-the-user-details-ip-name-duration-after-login-using-php#comment34685114_22754211) - Time difference between my comment and your answer: 2 minutes. Now wait for the OP to probably ask for code; I hope you're ready ;-)